# Beautiful Soup scrape of table is returning list of strings instead of list of lists

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using Beautiful Soup to scrape website is returning list of strings instead of list of lists.

I tried a .replace but it is not working on the list in a loop.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import csv
import pandas as pd
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/d/duncati01/gamelog/2015').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

f = csv.writer(open('bball_ref.csv','w'))

body = soup.body    
table = soup.select('#pgl_basic')
table_rows = table[0].find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]

    f.writerow([row])

with open('bball_ref.csv') as csvfile:
    bball_ref = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",")
    rows = []
    for row in bball_ref:
        rows.append(row)
```

Comment: then convert list to strings?

Comment: What is your expected outcome ? and actual ?

Comment: if you wanna mantain order, i suggest to iterate TR's (rows) and extract tds

Comment: `row` is a list, so `f.writerow([row])` then makes it a list containing the `row` list.  Also, you don't close `f` before opening it for the read.

Comment: @Alexander that was exactly what was wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` is already a list, you don't need to put another list around it when you call `f.writerow()`. It should be

```
f.writerow(list)
```

Comment: thanks, that was super simple. Not sure why I was trying to pass it as another list.